# Can I save the transactions data returned by Yodlee in my application database?

Tags: php, transactions, yodlee

Can I save the transactions data returned by Yodlee into my application database? I have browsed the web to get the answer, but all I could found is the security steps followed by Yodlee [here](http://www.freeagent.com/support/kb/banking/yodlee-faqs-security).

Task description:
1. Create an account on Yodlee. (Not saving username/passwords in application database)
2. Fetch the transaction history and save it in application database.

Are there any rules to save the transactions data into database? 
As I am not storing any username/passwords, do I need to look into PCI-DSS standards?
As transactions data is just a read only data returned by Yodlee, do I need to encrypt it before storing into application database?
Are there any legal clauses to store transactions data?

Answer (score 0):

PCI is required if you are storing card numbers.You should have good industry practices when storing the data into your application database. It's completely your choice to encrypt the stored data. Also storing data locally in your application reduces the effort of calling Yodlee every time a user wants to see their data.